# USB bootable computer doesn't recognize the content of the key

Tags: usb

I'm a noob and this is my deflowering with Ubuntu. (stop laughing at me)

I have a old computer with just XP on it. Cd-ROM devices installed but out of order and seems to be able to boot on USB ( it says "removable" in the BIOS in the Boot sequence order ). I have 2 differents HDD with NTFS partitions also.

I have made a usb bootable stick with LiLi and it works just fine on my other computer (more recent). So I know this stick is working well.

I put this stick in the old Xp computer, with the BIOS booting on this "removal" first, and it says "insert disk system blablabla..." in short: No!
In the Boot sequence order, I have the choice between HDD, CD, USB-CD, and Removal. I tried also with USB-CD, same result.

So, like a noob, I loaded the content of the key on my other HDD (NTFS). Windows knew that HDD was now Ubuntu bootable as I got the proper icon after in "my computer". I went back to my Bios, set the boot on this HDD first, and ... same result: Insert disk system.

Why? And what can I do to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Benoit - if you have lost your login credentials - please click the link at the bottom of the page and ask for your accounts to be merged.  For replies you should edit your question with new information - the answer section is for answers to your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partition from which you want to install Ubuntu (for example the USB stick) could **not** be **NTFS**.

To enable USB boot, check the BIOS for **HDD boot priority**. In some hardwares to boot from a USB stick, you must choose HDD in boot priorities and USB stick in HDD priorities  (of course you should insert USB stick before you enter the BIOS).

Answer (score 1):

Old computers tend to have different ideas about what is a bootable USB where even the type of USB key can make a differenece.

As your computer can boot from a CD I think you will have more sucess with the Live CD which you can gt here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

It will alo allow you to see what Ubuntu will see of your computer without installing anything. ie wether Network card works